# take value from file upload(value is image) and insert database by entityframework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to take value from file uploaded (value is image) and insert it into database through EntityFramework.

```
   int a = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["reqid"].ToString());

   MasterPackEntities context = new MasterPackEntities();

   news c = context.news.First(s => s.id == a);

   c.title = tbtitle.Text;
   c.details = Editor1.Content;
   c.pic =  ??????;
   context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Actually storing images in a relational database is not a good solution. Instead of storing in database save the image into disk and store only the path of it in the database. Then serve it from disk.

Comment: @Mecek This is worth a read as it depends on the image size - http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the image to a byte array.

So, assuming you have one of [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx):

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="imgUpload" runat="server"  />
```

You can just use:

```
 c.pic = imgUpload.FileBytes;
```

Also, as you are storing the images in a database, I would suggest *considering* [lazy loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) the pic property to see if it makes sense for your scenario.

Comment: @JensKloster Teehee, I'd suggest this approach